# Why are the strings not the same?

Tags: vb.net

My current code is:

```
Dim currentversion As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\lol\update\currentversion.txt")
Dim newversion As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\lol\update\new.txt")

If currentversion Is newversion Then
    MessageBox.Show("VERSION IS THE SAME")
End If
If currentversion Is Not newversion Then
    MessageBox.Show("VERSION IS NOT THE SAME")
End If
```

Why are the strings not the same? What's wrong?
In both text files is the same MEGA link, like "https://mega.nz/#!i8NgdfgdfgvufFf638vqGt7sA_yGdrefdgeVrnf_E3434" (link inst real now).

Thx for ur help!

Comment: It would be usual to use `=` and `<>` for equality and non-equality of strings. Do you have a reason to want to use `Is`? Also, you should use [`Option Strict On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx).

Comment: Same result there, I already tried. But thx for ur quick answer :) Option Strict On? What's this and how to use it?

Comment: For your convenience, I made the text "Option Strict On" a link to its documentation in my previous comment. If you inspect the file sizes of the two files, are they different? There could be, e.g. a new line character in one of them.

Comment: You are right, in one of them is an new line. I'll try to fix it :) Thx alot!

Comment: Fixed it using "currentversion = currentversion.Trim()", all fine now :)

Answer (score 4):

Because they're different objects:

```
Dim currentversion
Dim newversion
```

Separate variables, separate instances in memory, separate references.  And [the `Is` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx) compares *references*, not values.  If you want to compare the values, you're looking for the *equals* operator:

```
If currentversion = newversion Then
  '...
Else
  '...
End If
```

Or perhaps `.Equals()` depending on the objects being compared and if they implement that:

```
If currentversion.Equals(newversion) Then
  '...
Else
  '...
End If
```

Beyond that, it's possible that the strings *aren't* equal.  They are being read from different files after all...

Comment: Great answer, but be sure to UNDERSTAND the StringComparison enumerator behind .Equals:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Same result :/ You think it's better if both links are in the same file? Can I compare two different lines in one text file then?

Comment: @hannir: When you debug the code, what are the actual values of those variables?

Comment: Looks like the same. But like another dude said it's because in one of them is a new blank line. I'll try to fix :)

Comment: @David For a complete answer, if two variables are different objects, then why does `Dim a = "ABC" : Dim b = "ABC" : If a Is b Then MsgBox("SAME!")` show the MessageBox?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I'd actually only be guessing at that, but is it because of optimization of string literals?

Comment: @David As I understand it, yes, the two objects point to the same literal in some sort of table of strings formed by the compiler. I could be wrong: it would have been of interest to me if you had a definitive answer. Modifying the strings at run-time (`Dim a = "ABC" : Dim b = "ABCD" : b = b.Substring(0, 3) : If a Is b Then MsgBox("SAME!")`) does *not* show the MessageBox.

Comment: Fixed it using "currentversion = currentversion.Trim()", all fine now :)